# Adding count to ggplot boxplot based on a count in another column of the dataframe

Tags: r

```
df2<-data.frame(id=c("a","f","f","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","",""),
                var=c(12,20,15,18,10,30,5,8,5,5,3,5),
                group=c(rep("group1", times=5), rep("group2", times=5), rep("",times=2)))


give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = max(x)+1, label = length(x)))
}
ggplot(data=subset(df2, id != ""), aes(x = reorder(group, -var), y = var)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", 
               position = position_jitter(height=1, width = 0))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=11, vjust = -.005))+
  ggtitle("Title")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("value")
```

In the above graph I would like a count of the unique variables in 'var' column in 'df2'. So that in the resulting plot group1 has 3 and group2 has 2 above the boxplot. I believe the answer lies in 'label= ' in the function, however, I am unable to specify what I want correctly.
Ideas?